# Some mp4 videos are not playing in video.js

Tags: video.js

I can't play few mp4 video with mp4v codecs. Other mp4 videos with .avc plays fine. is this a bug or i am missing something? Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

If only some files won't play, these files may be encoded the wrong way. Check, if the videos are being played directly by the browser, without VideoJS and if this isn't the case, check their encoding (for example with http://mediaarea.net/de/MediaInfo).